# Campo padrão para select no illuminate/html

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estou com um problema e já procurei na internet pela solução. Sem sucesso!

Tenho um formulário e dentro dele, um select preenchido automaticamente:

```
{!! Form::select('categoria_id', $categorias, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Ok, funciona. Porém preciso criar um **option com value vazio**. 
Tipo: "**Selecione uma opção**", aí que está o problema. Já tentei várias formas, mas o que achei era pra outra versão do Laravel e nada feito.

Comment: como é o objeto `$categorias` ? `{!! Form::select('categoria_id', array_add($categorias, '', 'Selecione uma opção'), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}` será que resolve?

Comment: @Leandro Amorim, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse problema foi resolvido recentemente no [Laravel Collective](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/issues/60).

```
{!! Form::select('size', ['dados' => 'no', 'seu' => 'select'], null, ['placeholder' => 'Selecione uma opção']) !!}
```

Caso não esteja utilizando ele na sua aplicação, recomendo passar a usá-lo.

O componente `Form` foi retirado do core do Laravel a partir da versão 5, [conforme pode ver na documentação](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade).

> If you're using Form or HTML helpers, you will see an error stating `class 'Form' not found` or `class 'Html' not found`. The Form and HTML helpers have been deprecated in Laravel 5.0; however, there are community-driven replacements such as those maintained by the [Laravel Collective](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html).

Verifique se seu `composer.json` está utilizando o `laravelcollective/html`. Caso negativo siga o [passo a passo da sua instalação](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.